# Prove that the following set of triples forms a convex polytope

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Take $a,\,b,\,c,\,d \in \mathbb R_+$ such that $a+b+c+d=1$. Define:
\begin{equation}
x_1 = \min(a+b,\,c+d)\,,\qquad x_2 = \min(a+c,\,b+d)\,,\qquad x_3 = \min(a+d,\,b+c)\;.
\end{equation}
I would like to prove that the set of all possible triples $(x_1,\,x_2,\,x_3)$ of this form is a convex polytope in $\mathbb R^3$.

I am not sure if this is completely obvious or not. My first approach was to try to rewrite the set in question as (the projection of) the feasible region of a linear program, e.g. $x_1 = \min(a+b,\,c+d)$ is equivalent to $x_1\geq \min(a+b,\,c+d)$ and $x_1\leq \min(a+b,\,c+d)$. The latter is equivalent to $x_1\leq a+b \land x_1 \leq c+d$. But the former is nonlinear, so I am stuck.

Comment: It is not completely obvious (it isn't true that you can apply an arbitrary mapping with each coordinate mapping being the minimum of several linear forms to an arbitrary convex set and get a convex set again, so any approach that is too general, like the one you are trying, will fail) but not very hard either. The polytope in question is just $0\le x_i\le 1/2$, $x_i+x_j\ge x_k$ ($\{i,j,k\}=\{1,2,3\}$.) . That $x_k$ must satisfy these inequalities is immediate. For the existence, just solve $a+b=x_1,a+c=x_2,b+c=x_3$ and put $d=1-\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}2$. Also, this is a question for MSE, not MO.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was hoping for a solution which could be generalized, in line with what you write. For instance, the next case I have to deal with is $x_1=\min(a+b+c,d+e+f)$, $x_2=\min(a+b+d,c+e+f)$, $x_3=\min(a+c+e,b+d+f)$, $x_4=\min(a+d+e,b+c+f)$, $a+b+c+d+e+f=1$, $a,b,c,d,e,f\in\mathbb R_+$. Sorry about the MSE vs MO, don't know if it is possible to migrate it from one to the other.

Comment: So post the *full* question then as you have it. There is no full generality here but we may be able to figure out just as much as you want. And the full version may be suitable for MO too. It was just the version you posted that was a routine exercise.

Comment: Hint for handling some of the general situation: The intersection of (at least finitely many) convex sets is convex.  Gerhard "And Maybe Infinitely Many Too" Paseman, 2017.12.14.